# How do I configure my Django serializer to reuse a model if exists based on its unique constraint?

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, many-to-many, unique

I'm using Django 2.0 and Python 3.7.  I have the following models, one used as a ManyToMany by the other ...

```
class CoopTypeManager(models.Manager):

    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get_or_create(name=name)[0]


class CoopType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)

    objects = CoopTypeManager()
...
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType)
    address = AddressField(on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

I have these serializers set up ...

```
class CoopTypeField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    queryset = CoopType.objects

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if type(data) == dict:
            cooptype, created = CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**data)
            # Replace the dict with the ID of the newly obtained object
            data = cooptype.pk
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
...
class CoopTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CoopType
        fields = ['id', 'name']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `CoopType` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return CoopType.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `CoopType` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
...
class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    types = CoopTypeSerializer(many=True)
    address = AddressTypeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Coop
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'types', 'address', 'phone', 'enabled', 'email', 'web_site']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'phone': {
                'required': False,
                'allow_blank': True
            }
        }

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['types'] = CoopTypeSerializer(instance.types).data
        rep['address'] = AddressSerializer(instance.address).data
        return rep

    def create(self, validated_data):
        #"""
        #Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        #"""
        coop_types = validated_data.pop('types', {})
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        for item in coop_types:
            coop_type, _ = CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**item)
            instance.types.add(coop_type)
        return instance
```

but POST requests with payloads like the below

```
{
        "name": "7899",
        "types": [
            {"name": "Library"}
        ],
        "address": {
            "formatted": "222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza, Suite 1212",
            "locality": {
                "name": "Chicago",
                "postal_code": "60654",
                "state": 19313
            }
        },
        "enabled": true,
        "phone": "7739441426",
        "email": "myemail@msn.com",
        "web_site": "http://www.1871.com/"
}
```

result in these errors.

```
{"types":[{"name":["coop type with this name already exists."]}]}
```

if the type name already exists.  How can I adjust what I have to re-use an existing entry instead of attempting to create a new one?

**Edit:** To see this problem in action, the Git repo is here -- https://github.com/chicommons/maps , so you could run

```
git clone https://github.com/chicommons/maps.git
cd maps
docker-compose up
```

and then run the test script

```
sh web/scripts/test_post_req.sh
```

Comment: As I said in one of your questions, unique_together = ("name",) doesn't make any sense, remove it, apart from that the repository/project didn't run as is

Comment: Hi @ArakkalAbu, I think you're responding to an old question.  Neither in this question nor the Git repo are there any "unique_together" references.

Comment: [github code-base](https://github.com/chicommons/maps/blob/86daa3133aa477e7399c6b04ae9dae073b947525/web/maps/models.py#L21) have `unique_together = ("name",)`  in models. Hope you already figure it out

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated the repo to remove that as well.  However, even still, the problem remains ('{"types":[{"name":["coop type with this name already exists."]}]}' upon attempting to create a new entity using the test script)

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61200333/12578202 and give a try @Dave

Comment: Try addressing the uniqueness requirement directly by adding `extra_kwargs = {"name": {"required": False}}` to `CoopTypesSerializer.Meta`.  If that doesn't work, make sure that's the right kwargs as don't normally handle it manually.

Comment: Hi @clayfond, Thanks for the suggestion -- gave it a whirl but the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
`coop_type, _ = CoopType.objects.get_or_create(name=item['name'])`

Comment: You're talking about in the CoopSerializer's "create" method?  I tried subbing in what you have but I'm still seeing the error.  For completeness, could you provide the entire method body?  I included a GitHub link as an edit to my question if you want to see the class in context.

Comment: -Yes, `create` method of `CoopSerializer` class.
-I'm on restricted internet right now, can't access git links.

One more question, inside same create method i see:

`instance = super().create(validated_data)`

what exactly it is doing? I don't see any other class inherited other than ModelSerializer. How you tried to create without `super().create()`?

Comment: Tried commenting that out as well but same result.